# Cannot respond to Google Workspace Marketplace review

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a [Google Sheets Add-on](https://workspace.google.com/u/2/marketplace/app/sheetgo_connect_filter_merge_excel_csv/94172092257) listed on Google Workspace Marketplace (former G Suite Marketplace).

We sent the direct link above to users to review our Add-on, but many users are not able to leave a review. The rating stars and comment boxes are not available. I even tried myself with other Add-ons using different Gmail and Business accounts.

I have followed the [steps from Google Support](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F9281422%3Fhl%3Den&product_context=9281422&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a) page, and I still couldn't leave a review.

Is there something I'm missing? It cannot be that hard!

Researching and trying out old posts, I could leave a review in two different ways:

1. Using the [old G-Suite Marketplace URL](https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/sheetgo_connect_filter_merge_excel_csv/94172092257)
2. re-installing the Add-on.

Is this a bug in the Marketplace review?

Comment: This seems to be a possible `UI` issue on the Google Workspace Marketplace. It also seems there are no reported issue about this yet, at least on my [research on the Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20(%22workspace%20marketplace%22%20%7C%20%22workspace%20marketplace%20review%22)). For this matter, I believe it would be better if you could submit it as a possible issue on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) to be properly addressed & include all details (e.g. screenshot/screen-record that demonstrates the issue etc).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report, we are working on a fix.

Comment: The issue should be fixed now, please let me know if that's not the case.